# How to correctly preserve branch/merge history of an SVN repository when migrating to GIT

Tags: svn, git, version-control, git-svn

I'm trying to migrate a small SVN repository w/ 2000+ revs with 10+ branches to GIT. Branches sometimes merge contents from other branches. My main choice, was obvisously to use:

```
git svn clone -s URL
```

However, my GIT history only preserved the branching information and never shows a merge. Having an hard time googling for this too... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svn only very recently added merge tracking.  Does your version of subversion support it?  If it does, do you know how it actually communicates that to git so that git could model it as well?

Comment: It does support it, and it seems the answer lies in writing a decent grafts file. But I can't find any scripts that look for merge information on an SVN rep and populate grafts.